# Is eval that evil?

Tags: mongodb, eval

I understand that [`eval`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) locks the whole database, which can't be good for throughput - however I have a scenario where a very specific transaction involving several documents must be isolated.

Because that transaction does not happen very often and is fairly quick (a few updates on indexed queries), I was thinking of using `eval` to execute it.

Are their any pitfalls that I should be aware of (I have seen several eval=evil posts but without much explanation)?
Does it make a difference if the database is part of a replica set?

Comment: eval's evil because in pretty much any language/context it's the equivalent of standing out on a street and inviting random passersby into your house with "make yourself at home". Unless you're extraordinarily careful, and have considered ALL possible outcomes, eval can quite easily start something that can't be stopped.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "eval" in your case?  What exactly do you propose to run?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I have a document like `{ version: 7, isCurrent: true}` when I insert a new document with `version: 8`, I need to set `isCurrent` to true on that new document and false on all the others so that at any point in time, there is at most one document with `isCurrent: true` (the actual use case is more complicated but that's the basic idea and is a fairly hard requirement).

Comment: So it would look like `db.eval(function() { db.coll.find({}).forEach(function(e) { e.isCurrent = (e.current == e.version); db.coll.save(e); }); });`.

Comment: And have you considered what happens if the operation fails half way through?  There is no rollback in the database - the changes will only be isolated if the entire set of ops in eval succeeds normally.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes I understand that I only get isolation, not atomicity.

Comment: in case of failure part way through you won't get isolation. Have you considered a different schema to address this requirement?

Comment: You can't do `eval` in a sharded cluster, but they work in a replica-set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many developers would suggest using `eval` is "evil" as their are obvious security concerns with potentially unsanitized JavaScript code executing within the context of the MongoDB instance. Normally MongoDB is immune to those types of injection attacks.

Some of the performance issues of using JavaScript in MongoDB via the `eval` command are mitigated in version [2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/), as muliple JavaScript operations can execute at the same time (depending on the setting of the `nolock` option). By default though, it takes a global lock (which is what you specifically want apparently).

When a `eval` is being used to try to perform an (ACID-like) transactional update to several documents, there's one primary concern. The biggest issue is that if all operations must succeed for the data to be in a consistent state, the developer is running the risk that a failure mid-way through the operation may result in a partially complete update to the database (like a hardware failure for example). Depending on the nature of the work being performed, replication settings, etc., the data may be OK, or may not.

For situations where database corruption could occur as a result of a partially complete `eval` operation, I would suggest considering an alternative schema design and avoiding `eval`. That's not to say that it wouldn't work 99.9999% of the time, it's really up to you to decide ultimately whether it's worth the risk.

In the case you describe, there are a few options:

```
{ version: 7, isCurrent: true}
```

When a `version 8` document becomes current, you could for example:

- Create a second document that contains the current version, this would be an atomic set operation. It would mean that all reads would potentially need to read the "find the current version" document first, followed by the read of the full document.
- Use a timestamp in place of a `boolean` value. Find the most current document based on timestamp (and your code could clear out the fields of older documents if desired once the now current document has been set)